# I am searching a list of tuples for 3 strings

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, for example.

```
[('ABC', 'Abcair', 1.50), ('DEF', 'Defir', 5.60), ('GHI', 'Ghiair',3.22), ('ANZ', 'Anzplace', 26.25), ('ARG', 'Argair', 12.22), ('CEN', 'Cenair', 11.22), ('CNU', 'Cununun',3.01)]
```

I have an input command as such

```
code_input = input('Please list portfolio: ').upper()
```

Where a person will input any number of 3 letter codes separated by a comma, which I then format using

```
no_spaces_codes = code_input.replace(" ", "")
code_list = no_spaces_codes.split(",")
```

So, `"Ank , ABc,DEF"` becomes `['ANK', 'ABC', 'DEF']`

Then I print these headings formatted

```
header="{0:<6}{1:<20}{2:>8}".format("Code","Place","Number")
print(header)
```

I then need to search the list of tuples for the 3 letter codes and print the values under the
headings formatted the same way eg and codes not in the list will not be printed.

```
Code  Name                   Price
ABC   Abcair                  5.30
DEF   Defair                 11.22
```

I have gotten this far.

```
for code in b:
    if code[0] == (code_list[1]):
        print(code[:])
        break
```

Which prints

```
Code  Name                   Price
('CEN', 'Contact', 11.22)
```

But I cannot get any further than this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with:

```
place, price = next((c[1:] for c in b if c[0] == code_input), ('Not found', 0))
```

but you really want to use a dictionary instead:

```
code_dict = {k: (v, p) for k, v, p in b}
```

after which matching becomes a simple lookup:

```
place, price = code_dict.get(code_input, ('Not found', 0))
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> b = [('ABC', 'Abcair', 1.50), ('DEF', 'Defir', 5.60), ('GHI', 'Ghiair',3.22), ('ANZ', 'Anzplace', 26.25), ('ARG', 'Argair', 12.22), ('CEN', 'Cenair', 11.22), ('CNU', 'Cununun',3.01)]
>>> code_input = 'CEN'
>>> place, price = next((c[1:] for c in b if c[0] == code_input), ('Not found', 0))
>>> print code_input, place, price
CEN Cenair 11.22
>>> code_dict = {k: (v, p) for k, v, p in b}
>>> place, price = code_dict.get(code_input, ('Not found', 0))
>>> print code_input, place, price
CEN Cenair 11.22
```

With the `code_dict` mapping, lookups will be *much, much faster* when doing multiple lookups, especially when there are non-existing entries in the list. To put this together with the rest of your code:

```
code_input = input('Please list portfolio: ').upper()
code_dict = {k: (v, p) for k, v, p in b}

line="{0:<6}{1:<20}{2:>8}"
print line.format("Code", "Place", "Number")

for code in code_input.split(','):
    code = code.strip()
    if code not in code_dict:
        continue  # skip codes not in the mapping
    place, price = code_dict[code]
    print line.format(code, place, price)
```

Which for your `"Ank , ABc,DEF"` input would print:

```
Code  Place                 Number
ABC   Abcair                   1.5
DEF   Defir                    5.6
```

Comment: According to the question, code_input can be a list of several keys.

Comment: @Dhara: You can loop over `code_input` and operate *per input code* just as easily.

Comment: I know, it's just while that the OP did manage to find and print results for a single input_code, he seems to have had trouble with the rest of the input codes. Perhaps you should edit how to do that into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [v for v in list_of_tuples if v[0] in code_list]
for v in result:
    print(v) # Or format 'v' tuple in any way you want.
```